# Getting Error coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found after adding few lines in the file

Tags: python, unicode

```
from sys import argv

script,filename = argv

print "Will truncate the file : %s" %filename
print "If you wish to continue press \"Return\" or press CNTRL-C"

raw_input("?")

target = open(filename,"w")

print "We are truncating the file"

target.truncate()

print "File is truncated"

print "Now enter the three lines to add into the file"

line1 = raw_input("Line_1 : ")
line2 = raw_input("Line_2 : ")
line3 = raw_input("Line_3 : ")

print "Adding these line is in progress"

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "Writter is completed"
target.close()
**print "Here is the new file :\n",open(target,mode='r', buffering=-1).read()**

target.close()
```

I am trying to truncate a file and then writting few lines in it , after that when Iclose the file and try to rreopen it , it's giving me the below error

> Error is in the highlighted part .. can you please help me what could
>   be the error

Comment: Post the error you're getting too!

Comment: TypError : Unicode: need string or buffer, file found ..

Comment: I think the error is when I was calling the Open function once again .. instead of passing the open file stream I should pass the file name .. and it worked now

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because open is looking for a file name, and you're passing to it the file object itself.
[From the docs on open function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open):

> The first two arguments are the same as for stdio‘s fopen(): name is
>   the file name to be opened, and mode is a string indicating how the
>   file is to be opened.